# Scope of a structure in C language

Tags: c, struct, scope, global

Could someone explain in simple terms what is meant by this?

> The scope of a structure begins at its appearance in a type specifier, and persists to the end of the translation unit (for declarations at the external level) or to the end of the block (for declarations within a function)"

— *"C, A Reference Manual"* by Samuel Harbison

Comment: It means the type is in scope from the moment it is defined until either the end of the translation unit (think roughly "file") or the end of the current nesting level (e.g. `{` `}`)

Comment: Yes, I know the scope of identifiers, blocks ecc. I've been programming in C for years. But I'd like to know exactly what is the meaning of this quote from the book

Comment: @alessiosolari: When you respond to a comment, use “@username” in it so they will be notified of the response.

Comment: @paddy: Blocks are not just compound statements (`{…}`). Each loop statement is a block. Each body of a loop statement is a block. Each `if` and `switch` statement is a block. Each substatement of an `if` or `switch` is a block. In particular, the scopes of items declared in the `(…)` of a `for` statement end at the end of the `for` statement, not at the end of the block the `for` statement is in.

Answer (score 4):

The Compiler traverses your code and encounters a struct definition.

This is where the struct comes into existence and is known and recognized by the compiler (scope begins).

A Translation unit is generally a .c file. So your struct is known until the compiler has finished compiling the .c file.

If you have declared the struct inside a block (for example a function), it is only known inside that function and will be out of scope outside.

If your struct is defined in a .h file, the contents of that .h file are copied everywhere you do a `#include "file.h"`. So your struct is then known in every translation unit (file) it is included in.

Comment: _"A Translation unit is generally a .c file"_ - Perhaps it would be clearer with _"A Translation unit is generally a `.c` file, including all the header files it has `#include`d"_ or something similar, like _"A source file together with all the headers
and source files included via the preprocessing directive `#include` is known as a preprocessing
translation unit."_

Comment: plus _"After preprocessing, a preprocessing translation unit is called a translation unit."_ (the last two quotes are from the C23 draft).

Comment: Re “If you have declared the struct inside a block (for example a function), it is only known inside that function and will be out of scope outside”: A structure declared anew (some structure declarations redeclare a previously visible structure) inside a block is known inside that block, which may be less than the function. Re “This is where the struct comes into existence”: Specifically, the structure type is known; no structure object comes into existence due to the specification of a structure type.

Answer (score 2):

Asking for detailed explanations of statements about C in third-party books is problematic because the C standard is definitive, so any interpretation of the author’s words that differ from the C standard may explain what the author meant but is wrong in regard to what the C standard says.

Let’s start with scope. The quote mentions two scopes—file scope (“to the end of the translation unit”) and block scope. However, structure declarations can appear in three scopes. The third scope is function prototype scope. It is generally not useful for structure declarations but needs to be understood to interpret and avoid the errors that arise from it. (There is a fourth scope, function scope, that is relevant only for labels.)

In C 2018 6.2.1, the C standard defines scope to be a region of source code where an identifier is visible (can be used in association with a particular declaration of it). It does not define scope for types but does refer to scopes of types as if they followed rules similar to those for identifiers. For this purpose, the scope of a type is the region of source code where it is effectively known.

For a structure, the *type-specifier* is one of two grammatical forms in C 2018 6.7.2.1:

- `struct identifieroptional { struct-declaration-list }`.
- `struct identifier`.

(Other type specifiers include similar forms for `union` and basic types such as `long int`.)

In C 2018 6.7.2.3, the C standard further distinguishes four forms of structure declaration:

1. `struct identifieroptional { struct-declaration-list }`.
2. `struct identifier` immediately followed by `;`.
3. `struct identifier` not immediately followed by `{` or `;` and without a previous visible declaration of `identifier` as a tag.
4. `struct identifier` not immediately followed by `{` or `;` and with a previous visible declaration of `identifier` as a tag.

For forms 1 to 3, the structure type is known from where its *type-specifier* appears to the end of its scope:

- If forms 1 to 3 appear at file scope, the structure type is known from where the *type-specifier* appears until the end of the translation unit. (The translation unit is the source file being compiled, including all of the files it includes, directly or indirectly.)
- If forms 1 to 3 appear inside a block or inside the parameter declarations of a function definition, the structure type is known from where the *type-specifier* appears until the end of block (if in a block) or the end of the block that defines the function (if inside parameter declarations).
- If forms 1 to 3 appear inside the parameter declarations of a function declaration that is not a definition, the structure type is known from where the *type-specifier* appears until the end of the function declaration (specifically at the end of its *declarator*).

In form 4, the scope of the type does not start at the type specifier because this form specifies the same type as the already visible declaration. So the scope started at the earlier *type-specifier* (or, if it is also of this form, at a yet earlier *type-specifier* and so on), and it also ends with the scope associated with that earlier *type-specifier*.

This rule about form 4 is what allows us to use a structure type from an outer scope:

```
struct foo { int i, j; };

int bar(struct foo *p)
{
    return p->j;
}
```

If `struct foo *p` declared a new type, we could not properly use the initial `struct foo` type in parameters to functions or inside functions, because that `struct foo` would be a new and different type from any `struct foo` outside the function.

This is also why we need to be aware of function prototype scope. Function prototype scope is entirely within a function declaration that is not a function definition, such as:

```
void bar(struct foo *p);
```

Even though there is no block here, the scope of `struct foo` ends at the `)` that ends the function declarator. This structure declaration has form 3, so it makes a new type. That means if we do not declare `struct foo` before the prototype, as in this code:

```
int bar(struct foo *p);

struct foo { int i, j; };

int bar(struct foo *p)
{
    return p->j;
}
```

then the prototype will use a different type for `struct foo` than the later declarations, even though they have the same name. This results in a compiler message that is confusing to the unaware, involving the fact that one type named `struct foo` is not compatible with another type also named `struct foo`. So `struct foo` must be declared before it is used in a function prototype.

Here is another example of where structure declarations can be tricky:

```
struct a *p = 0;
struct b *q = 0;
{
    struct b;         // Form 2, declares a new type.
    struct a *r = p;  // Okay, uses same type for r as for p.
    struct b *s = q;  // Wrong, uses different type for s than for q.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a "structure" in your code as a box with labels where you can put various types of data. The "scope" of this box, which you create, specifies where in your code you can use and access it. You can utilize the box anywhere in your entire program if you construct it outside of a function. The box, however, can only be used if it is created inside of a function.

Let us consider this `struct` named `string`.

```c
typedef struct my_str {
    char str[100];
    unsigned len;
} string;
```

##### Example 1:

```c
// @file: myheader.h

string mah_string;

// rest of your code
// now variable `mah_string` can be used in any function in the header file and the file that includes your header file.
// Hence, making the use case (*scope*) of your variable global
```

##### Example 2:

```c
void print_my_name_using_struct()
{ 
    string my_local_str;
    my_local_str.str = "Tushar";
    my_local_str.len = 6; // length of "Tushar"
    printf("%s\n", my_local_str.str);

// now the use case (*scope*) of `my_local_str` is only limited to the function `print_my_name_using_struct` 
// and CANNOT be used outside of it.
}
```